# Shows thumbnails for images and open documents easily in the same library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365

### Goal

To have a space that has a list of projects that is filterable like a typical list with metadata (columns). Clicking a project would take you to another space showing the following:

- General project information (text/metadata)
- Documents (typically PDFs - qty:10-20ish)
- Images (JPGs - qty: 50-100+) related to that project

---

I'm on SharePoint Online/Office 365.

I don't care about any gallery functionality, I just want to be able to view reasonable thumbnails when browsing the list of files.

I need it to be mobile friendly. The images should display (or have the option to display) as thumbnails.

### What I've Tried

**Document Set** - My first thought was to set this up with a Document Set as the project: The Welcome Page shows the text about the project, a list of PDFs in the root area of the Document Set, and an *images* folder inside the Document Set for all images. It all technically works, but does not show images as thumbnails, just a list of filenames. Thumbnails are important for user adoption.

**Document Set + Picture Library App** - I also tried creating my initial document library as a Picture Library App instead, and this worked ok for showing the images (although the user still had to manually choose thumbnails when viewing images), but then the PDFs were not single clickable - clicking the PDF brings up the document properties which contains a link to the actual PDF file, but that process is cumbersome. This is probably better than the generic document library for our needs, but is still not ideal.

**Separate Photo + Document Libraries** - My third thought was to use a lookup column to link Document Sets from a *Document* Library to Document Sets in a separate *Picture* Library - in this scenario, each project would have a Document Set in each library. But I don't think this will be very user friendly, and also not accessible on mobile (unless someone has tips for showing the Document Set Welcome Page on mobile).

### Question

Have I exhausted all of the possibilities? Is there a better way to set this up that will still meet my needs?